# Ajuda em Engine de Noticias RSS

Tags: javascript, css, rss

Boa noite galera,

Estou tentando fazer uma engine de noticias RSS bem ao estilo televisão o código é aberto e pode ser visto no [Github](https://github.com/Miguelcpjava/engine-news-rss), estou tentando fazer com os efeitos fadeout e fadein porém só está sendo mostrado a última noticias como pode ver no exemplo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71hhcjwx/1/) além disso gostaria que também fosse mostrado de vários feeds rss e não só com um como está no exemplo. E também melhor o visual pois  quando começa a aparecer as notícias a layout fica de fora da margem rosa.

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço muito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coisas a melhorar no teu código:

- tira o CSS do HTML
- separa a lógica de mudar noticias do ajax
- cria o HTML fora do gerador de noticias

Sugestão:

Usa uma função assim:

```
 var alternador = (function(el, delay) {
    el = $(el);
    var noticias = [];
    var p = el.find('p');
    var a = el.find('a');

    var index = 0;

    function mostrarProxima() {
        el.fadeIn();
        var value = noticias[index++];
        a.html(value.title);
        a.attr('href', value.link);
        // p.html(value.content); // <- caso queiras usar mais tarde
        el.delay(2000).fadeOut();
        if (index == noticias.length) index = 0;
    }
    setInterval(mostrarProxima, delay || 3000);
    return function(_noticias) {
        noticias = _noticias;
    }
})('#result', 5000);
```

e depois dentro do ajax só tens de atualizar as noticias se fôr caso de ser preciso um refresh, assim:

```
values = xml.responseData.feed.entries;
alternador(values);
```

## Exemplo:

```js
$(function() {

    var alternador = (function(el, delay) {
        el = $(el);
        var noticias = [];
        var p = el.find('p');
        var a = el.find('a');

        var index = 0;

        function mostrarProxima() {
            el.fadeIn();
            var value = noticias[index++];
            a.html(value.title);
            a.attr('href', value.link);
            // p.html(value.content); // <- caso queiras usar mais tarde
            el.delay(2000).fadeOut();
            if (index == noticias.length) index = 0;
        }
        setInterval(mostrarProxima, delay || 3000);
        return function(_noticias) {
            noticias = _noticias;
        }
    })('#result', 5000);

    var urlRss = 'http://www.cidades.gov.br/ultimas-noticias?format=feed&type=rss';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(urlRss),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(xhr) {
            var erro = xhr.responseText;
            alert('Erro ao ler o feed: ' + erro);
        },
        success: function(xml) {
            values = xml.responseData.feed.entries;
            alternador(values);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#result li {
    list-style: none;
}

#result a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #224B9D;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 4em;
}

#titulo {
    background-color: #F95252;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

#header {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #7E9DBB;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
#header:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#header > div {
 padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="titulo">
            ::Noticias::
        </div>
        <div>
            Título
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" ¨>
        <ul id="result">
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>
                <p></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/osaebjdr/

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio, vou fazer isso e atualizar o código no Github! Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Alterei no github, com algumas modificações, já estou cadastrando issues.Valeu!